# How to add a marker with some details for Bar Chart using MPAndroidChart in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I created a stacked **BarChart using MPAndroidChart** library and now when the user **clicks** on a bar, I want to display a **marker** with some details as in the image bellow:
[image]

I found different topics on this subject but couldn't find a clear solution, so please help me if you can. Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
 for (item in dataTicketsList) {
        if (i <= 2) {

            val firstValue: String = transformDataForChart(item.values.first!!)
            hoursValuesArray.add(firstValue.toFloat())

            val secondValue: String = transformDataForChart(item.values.second!!)
            hoursValuesArray.add(secondValue.toFloat())

            val thirdValue: String = transformDataForChart(item.values.third!!)
            hoursValuesArray.add(thirdValue.toFloat())

            entriesVerticalBar.add(BarEntry(i, hoursValuesArray.toFloatArray()))
            i++
            hoursValuesArray.clear()

            if (item.label!!.contains("." + (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1).toString())) {
                val date: String = item.label!!.replace("." + (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1).toString(), "")
                barLabesArrayList.add(date)
            } else if (item.label!!.contains("." + (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)).toString())) {
                val date: String = item.label!!.replace("." + (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)).toString(), "")
                barLabesArrayList.add(date)
            }
        }
    }

    verticalBarChartColors.add(Color.rgb(89, 93, 223))
    verticalBarChartColors.add(Color.rgb(25, 227, 180))
    verticalBarChartColors.add(Color.rgb(85, 164, 206))
    val markerView = CustomMarkerView(requireContext(), R.layout.custom_marker_view_layout, hoursValuesArray )
    var barDataSet = BarDataSet(entriesVerticalBar, "")
    val barChart: BarChart = bar_chart_details
    barDataSet.colors = verticalBarChartColors
    barDataSet.valueTextSize = 8f
    barDataSet.stackLabels = arrayOf("00:00 - 06:00 h", "06:00 - 18:00 h", "18:00 - 24:00 h")
    barDataSet.valueTextColor = resources.getColor(R.color.white)
    val barData = BarData(barDataSet)
    barData.setValueFormatter(VerticalBarChart.DecimalRemover(DecimalFormat("###")))
    barChart.data = barData
    barChart.marker = markerView
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define your custom marker view declaring a class which extends the `MarkerView` class.

1. Define a custom layout for your marker view (`custom_marker_view.xml`).
   You could customize this layout with a layout or other views as you need.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

2. Create the custom class (`CustomMarkerView`) extending `MarkerView`.
   This class must receive the array of data displayed in the chart and override the `refreshContent` method, were the data will be displayed.
   The `getOffset` method is optional and it serves to adjust the position of the marker on the screen.

```
class CustomMarkerView(
        context: Context,
        layout: Int,
        private val dataToDisplay: MutableList<Float>
) : MarkerView(context, layout) {

    private var txtViewData: TextView? = null

    init {
        txtViewData = findViewById(R.id.txtViewData)
    }

    override fun refreshContent(e: Entry?, highlight: Highlight?) {
        try {
            val xAxis = e?.x?.toInt() ?: 0
            txtViewData?.text = dataToDisplay[xAxis].toString()
        } catch (e: IndexOutOfBoundsException) { }

        super.refreshContent(e, highlight)
    }

    override fun getOffset(): MPPointF {
        return MPPointF(-(width / 2f), -height.toFloat())
    }
}
```

3. You can then assign the marker to your chart with:

```
val marker = new CustomMarkerView(this, R.layout.custom_marker_view, <your-array-of-data>)
chart.marker = marker
```

Comment: Can you tell me please how the CustomMarkerView constructor will look like in kotlin? And the class declaration. please

Comment: Just edited my answer with a Kotlin version that should work.

Comment: I added my array as paramter but I got java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0. After that I checked if dataToDisplay.isNotEmpty but its not working. When I tap on a bar the marker is not displayed. What should I do?

Comment: Then, your array of data it's empty. Try to debug it with a `Log.d("myArray", dataToDisplay.toString())`, also I've added a `try ... catch` block to the code to avoid crashes.

Comment: Still not working. When I click on a bar nothing happens..

Comment: Because the `refreshContent` function catch the exception, since your list of data is empty, can you post your chart initialization code?

Comment: I added the code, please take a look. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231354/discussion-between-razvan22-and-luca-999).

Comment: @Razvan22 The `hoursValuesArray` is empty because you are calling `hoursValuesArray.clear()`, remove that line. Also, I've edited the `CustomMarkerView` to accept a `MutableList<Float>` parameter, since its the type of `hoursValuesArray`.

Comment: I changed to MutableList. But if I remove the hoursValuesArray.clear(), then each bar will contains the previous bar's values too, right? And that's not ok

Comment: You should create a global list to store your chart values and pass that to the `CustomMarkerView` initializer.

Comment: I have stacked bar chart and inside the markers are not displayed the values for each interval of a bar, I think something should be changed inside CustomMarkerView class..